How do I get windows to ignore security level and connect to the internet
Sometimes when I try to connect to hotel wifi, Windows tells me that it is at a lower security level that is due to be phased out.  It then cleverly offers me help on what to do but when I click on the link, it tries to open the browser, which then fails miserably to tell me anything except that there is no internet connection, which I knew anyway.
I managed to look at this link.  It suggests

Use another wifi network.  Can't do that, this is the only one available.
If using older wifi, consider changing the type of security.  I can't - the hotel controls this
If using older router, consider changing the router.  I can't - it is the hotel's router.

How do I force Windows to connect regardless of how old the security standard is?
Edit
The text says

The xxx Hotel isn't secure
This Wi-Fi network uses an older security
standard that's being phased out. We
recommend connecting to a different
network

There is a Learn more button but it only works if you have an internet connection.
Edit2
This is my own PC - not company owned or managed.  It is running W11 Prof.  I've noticed that it only happens in the afternoon/evening - possibly when the rest of the hotel is hammering the internet.  It sometimes connects but not always.

Edit 3
It happened again - this time, I just waited.  I did eventually connect after about 5 minutes.  I think it is just that the hotel network was too busy.

What's the actual security level of the network in question, out of curiosity? Is it one of those "open but with web login" networks that most places use, or is it using WPA and Windows complains about it not being WPA2, or is it using WEP?

Normally the hotel gives me a wifi password.  It doesn't say what it is - WPA, WEP or WPA2.  How do I find out?

I'd probably use Nirsoft tools though there are dozens that do the same thing (inSSIDer also popular, many "wifi analyzers" for Android as well). A bit surprising to still see such networks in the wild though, given that WPA2 became available in wireless routers nearly 20 years ago... And, does Windows actually refuse to connect, or does it just warn? I don't really recall it outright refusing to connect to WPA1 at least, so my suspicion actually is that the lack of internet access is unrelated to that. Does it work on your phone?

Whenever it has happened, windows refuses to connect sometimes.  Sometimes it connects and sometimes it is not, even with the router just outside the door.  Works when using the phone hotspot.

Can you please provide us with a screenshot, or exact quote of the message(s) you receive when you do this? The precise information you are getting will go a long way towards helping us understand the problem you are facing. Also, more details regarding your system will help: What version of Windows, what wireless adapter/system is in your computer, etc.

I'll have to park this until the next time I'm at a hotel that flashes up this message.  It only displays for about 2 seconds so if I manage to capture it, I'll add it to the question.

I found the popup with this text on Google Images, and it doesn't look anything like an error message or any other kind of barrier. It's a notification. I'm going to stick with my initial guess that Windows does connect to the Wi-Fi network and that it's the Wi-Fi network that has no further access... Post a screenshot of a Wi-Fi scan (using either the Windows tools mentioned earlier, or any Android app) to check what the hotel's Wi-Fi setup is actually like.

Is this a company owned or managed computer that you are using?

That message is not indicating that you are blocked. It is a warning informing you of an issue, but a Windows computer in a default state will still connect and work fine over that sort of network.
Reasons why your computer may NOT be working fine may include:

The computer you are using is owned and/or managed by someone else who has applied additional security policies and restrictions to it that include only allowing you to use more secure wireless types.
You have installed 3rd party security software that is enforcing a security policy preventing use of these older, less secure connection types.

If the former: Talk with your company IT folks regarding this. I doubt they'll change policy, but they may be able to offer alternate ways of connecting.
If the latter: review your security software settings, probably in a section called Network. If you don't see a setting there, try disabling the software and see if the problem goes away.
NOTE: Windows Defender is an adequate security tool for most computers already, and when you disable a 3rd party security suite, Defender should automatically take over.

Windows Defender is fine for a consumer device.  The reason Windows Defender should be replaced for Enterprise devices is because the needs for security are often different. A consume typically has complete control over their device, while a user of an enterprise device, is often managed.

Defender is used in a wide range of Enterprise systems too. It does have full reporting and management capabilities through Azure/Intune/SCCM/GP, reporting up to Microsoft's Security portal. It is the same client interface, but I believe it is branded "Microsoft Defender" in enterprise mode. But, if this is an enterprise computer, the question is really moot: OP needs to talk to their IT folks.

There is a YouTuber, Thor, who is an offensive security specialist former Blizzard employee, who also suggested that Windows Defender is fine.

Much of the best info comes from Youtubers named "Thor". lol. Sorry, I just found that detail funny.
